# Unable to write files to sub-directories of "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" directory in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, file-permissions

I'm working on a Qt C++ program that needs to write files to a sub-directory of the "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" directory. However, I'm encountering a problem where I can successfully write files within the WindowsApps directory itself, but not within any of its sub-directories.

I have attempted to run the program as both Administrator and "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" to gain the necessary permissions, but I still face the issue. When writing files to the "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" directory directly, I receive the "File written successfully" message, but when attempting to write to any sub-directory, I receive the "Failed to write file" message.

Here is the relevant code I am using:

```cpp
bool writeFile(const QString& filePath, const QString& content)
{
    QFile file(filePath);
    
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open file for writing:" << file.errorString();
        return false;
    }
    
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << content;
    
    file.close();
    
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString filePath = "C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MyApp_1.0.0.0/myFile.txt";
    QString content = "working";

    if (writeFile(filePath, content)) {
        qDebug() << "File written successfully";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Failed to write file";
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand why I am unable to write files to sub-directories of the "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" directory? Is there any additional step or permission I need to set in order to successfully write files in this scenario?

Comment: You are not supposed to write into this directory.  That's the point.  Why do you want to do this?  It's owned by `TrustedInstaller`.

Comment: I know it's owned by TrustedInstaller, and IOBit Unlocker works in this directory. However, I would prefer to either create my own program or use an open-source one. The reason is that I need to write into this directory because some programs I install within my Windows installation come from the Microsoft Store. I would like to create scripts to automate certain tasks within these directories, so i need to have read and write access. From my understanding, TrustedInstaller is an inaccessable group that can only be assigned to the SYSTEM account, which is why I tried using the SYSTEM account.

Comment: I know you don't want to hear this, but seriously, give up.  Even if you do manage to get this to work, you'll start to run afoul of the system integrity tools.

Comment: I know the risks of all of what i am doing but i am running all of this inside of a Virtual Machine anyway i run a Arch Linux host machine and have snapshots so i would still like to make scripts to automate things